# Reference an external script source in jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The list of options (var availableTags) for jQuery UI autocomplete will be sitting in a separate .js file. How can I reference that from within the jQuery call?

```
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
    });
```

So if it was CSS you could link to the file via ../js/autocomplete.js etc

**Edit:**

I've split this into 2 files but it's returning 'availableTags is not defined'

html

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/autocomplete.js"></script>
<script src="js/global.js"></script>
```

autocomplete.js

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
    ];
});
```

global.js

```
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just include the file with `<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/available-tags.js"></script>` and ensure the variable is in a scope that can be accessed when you need it.

#### main.js

```
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});
```

#### available-tags.js

```
var availableTags = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Just ensure you have included the tags first, or delegated their requirement until all scripts have been included.

If you have the variable bured somewhere, out of an accessible scope to your `autocomplete()` call, you can also explicitly make it global by setting it as a property of `window` (though globals should be kept to a minimum).

Comment: Thanks. It's still returning 'availableTags is not defined' for me though. I've edited my question to reflect